# Efficiently approximate Ax=b if you can choose values for A

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, linear-approximation

Here is the situation.

You have a black box **x**, whose values are not known to you, but you can choose values for **A** and generate the corresponding **b** value using **Ax=b**. There is some noise in the system so it is not possible to get an exact solution.

What is an efficient way to select values for **A**, to approximate a solution for **x**, using least squares approximation (or some other approximation algorithm if it would work better for this problem)?

So, it's like a least squares approximation with active feedback. Are there any algorithms for this?

I've tried doing some google searching and found nothing, it's a situation where I don't even know what keywords to search for, so any information to lead me in the right direction would be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you take $A$ to be the identity matrix?

Comment: If $A$ has all columns zero except the $i$th column, then $Ax$ will be the $i$th column of $A$ scaled by $x_i$, with noise. With repeated measurements you can get a better and better estimate of $x_i$.

Comment: I think yes, it can be the identity matrix. I'm working with a physical system, so the input can be anything (except all zeros). And there will be some values of b that change randomly, which I would like to be able to identify and ignore.

Comment: Thank you for the comment angryavian, that is a good point. However, (and I should have put this in the question) the **A** I'm working with has on the order of millions of columns so a more efficient solution is needed.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want $b$ to be significantly smaller than $x$, i.e. $A$ non-square. This problem is called "Compressed Sensing". maybe that search-term gives you something useful. good luck :)

Comment: @Simon Yes. "Compressed Sensing" I will look into that. Thank you!